# Use Entity Framework 6.0 in .net 4.0 application (wpf)

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I have a WPF application which uses .Net framework 4.I would like to use entity framwork 6 on my application for data access. Will I get all the entity framework 6 features in my .net 4.0 application?

Comment: Why is this a question? Do you have any evidence to the contrary, or do you experience any conflict when trying to reference EF6? Have you tried adding it? Did you look up the release notes and general documentation of Entity Framework 6? *Is your question based on anything other than the numerical difference of their version numbers?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can access all the features of Entity Framework 6 while using .NET 4.

Read this for complete information:

[Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532202.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just download from nuget and get cracking.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574253.aspx)